# how to untar the file and rename the folder in one command line operation?

Tags: shell, command-line

I want to download a file, untar it and rename the folder.

I am able to download the file and untar it with

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/sampletest/sample.tar.gz | tar xz
```

How can I rename the folder in the same command?

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/sampletest/sample.tar.gz | tar xz | mv ???????
```

I do not want to use the folder name explicitly in the command.

Comment: When you say you don't want to use the folder name explicitly, do you mean you want to rename the folder based on what the tar was originally named, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but not trivial. It's easier to create your own directory, cd into it, then pass `--strip-components 1` or `--strip-path 1` to `tar` if your tar (e.g. GNU Tar) supports it.

```
 File name transformations:

      --strip-components=NUMBER   strip NUMBER leading components from file
                                  names on extraction
      --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
                                  use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names
```

Answer (score 3):

If your system hasn't GNU `tar` installed, it might still have `pax` (a POSIX tool) available. The latter supports the `-s` option which allows arbitrary changes in the path name of the processed files.

That would then be:

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/sampletest/sample.tar.gz | gunzip | pax -r -s "/old/new/"
```